# How to remove blank space in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to remove white(blank) space in my application. Below Is my code .

```
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.amber),
          actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.amber),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            'News App',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 23,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                onPressed: () {
                  _showNotification();
                }),
          ],
        ),
        drawer: Menu(),
        body: Container(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: swiperImage(),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    child: newsList(),
                  ))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

> Here I display Image of my output, in this image top of the display I set swiper image and in remaining portion I set List view. So, I want to remove blank space in between this two widget. So, how can I do this?

[image: img]

Comment: Check your SwiperImage widget that has some bottom margin or newList widget have some top margin

Comment: There is no margin in my `SwiperImage` Widget. Do you have any other solution?  @jitsm555

Comment: This code is not enough to tell you why it causes this, But for now you can comment Expanded widget and add simple Text Widget and check whether blank space still exist or not

Comment: I did this. `Text Widget` does not contain space but when I use `Expanded widget` it has same problem. Here I share link of `pastebin` where I add my `SwiperImage` widget and `newsList` Widget. Check it and give solution if you have ant idea. [https://pastebin.com/KBfwAGuV] - @jitsm555

Comment: If  you are not able to get code then go to this link [https://pastebin.com/REeqRGqD]

Comment: Can you add Flexible Widget? and let me know if it works for you

Comment: I used `flexible widget` but it has same problem. - @jitsm555

Comment: Above links not working, how I can see your code

Comment: Check this link: [https://pastebin.com/raw/REeqRGqD] -@jitsm555

Comment: Can you reduce the height of SizeBox to 200 and check

Comment: No. it is not working brother, any other solution? - @jitsm555

Answer (score 1):

The space is inside the ListView. Add this code and it disappears in Listview.

in `ListView`:

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
    context: context,
    removeTop: true,
    child: ListView.builder()
)
```